# Slice of pointers and loop

Tags: loops, pointers, go, slice

I think this question where asked several times but I still confused:

I have following code:

```
type obj struct {
    s *string
}

var cmdsP = []*string {
    stringPointer("create"),
    stringPointer("delete"),
    stringPointer("update"),
}

var cmds = []string {
    "create",
    "delete",
    "update",
}

// []*string
func loop1() {
    slice := make([]obj, 0, 0)

    for _, cmd := range cmdsP {
        slice = append(slice, obj{cmd})
    }
    for _, o := range slice {
        fmt.Println(*o.s)
    }
}

// []string
func loop2() {
    slice := make([]obj, 0, 0)
    for _, cmd := range cmds {
        slice = append(slice, obj{&cmd})
    }
    for _, o := range slice {
        fmt.Println(*o.s)
    }
}

func stringPointer(v string) *string {
    return &v
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/65Le_8Pi3Mi

The only difference is in slice semantic `[]*string` and `[]string` how does it change behavior of `cmd` variable? Could you please draw or explain in details what happens in memory during iteration through two loops?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `range` on a collection, the go runtime initialises 2 memory locations; one for the index (in this case `_`), and one for the value `cmd`.

What range then does, is take each of the items in the collection and **copy them into the memory location that it created when you called `range`**.

This means that each of the items in the slice get put into that memory location one by one.

When you do `&cmd` you are taking a pointer. This pointer points to the shared memory location that each of the slice items are being copied into.

All of your pointers created using `&cmd` all point to the same memory location.

This means that after the `range` is done, the only value left in that memory location that your pointers are pointing to is the last value from the `range` iteration.

This is why you get the output

```
update
update
update
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in one case you are passing an address to struct and in other case you are passing a string value. So whenever you append an struct field to a slice it will going to update the existing value on same address. That's the reason you are getting only last value for pointer type slice of structs which is `update` in this case

```
// []string
func loop2() {
    slice := make([]obj, 0, 0)
    for _, cmd := range cmds {
        slice = append(slice, obj{&cmd})
    }
    for _, o := range slice {
        fmt.Println(*o.s)
    }
}
```

`&cmd` will point to same address which is updating its value to the same location in every iteration which is not the case when you are not passing address to `cmd` in `loop1`.

**Edited**
This is a slice of `[]obj` which has a field of pointer type *string

```
slice := make([]obj, 0, 0)
```

So when you are looping over it you are actually passing the address of `cmd` and assigning it to a pointer field.

To see the difference print the type and you will get the information for eg:

```
func loop1() {
    slice := make([]string, 0, 0)

    for _, cmd := range cmdsP {
        slice = append(slice, *cmd)
    }
    for _, o := range slice {
        fmt.Println(o)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", slice)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/HPFVs2RxVB-)

In above case you are creating a slice of string.

```
// []*string
func loop1() {
    slice := make([]obj, 0, 0)

    for _, cmd := range cmdsP {
        slice = append(slice, obj{cmd})
    }
    for _, o := range slice {
        fmt.Println(*o.s)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", slice)
}
```

While In second case you are creating a slice of `obj` struct which contains a field of pointer to `string`. They both are different cases. use `fmt` package to see the actual types of slices you are creating in `loop1` function

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ja8TK5sG6ya)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You said `So whenever you append an struct field to a slice` but if I append string field `slice := make([]string, 0, 0)` everything is fine. What is the difference? https://play.golang.org/p/7UdLlP2GiLw

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ Please check edited answer